# how to get source tag in RSS feed

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

Please, I have an RSS feed and need to get the source for every item. I'm using php and Samplepie.

for example the RSS feed is like that :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
  <channel>
    <title>Landofcode.com web tutorials updates</title>
    <link>http://www.landofcode.com</link>
    <description>Web development tutorials</description>
    <item>
      <title>Wacky news story</title>
      <link>http://www.reddit.com/r/wacky</link>
      <description>Guy runs into a car and drives it!</description>
      <source url="http://www.reddit.com/.rss">
      reddit.com:what's new online!
      </source>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>New HTML tutorials</title>
      <link>http://www.landofcode.com/html-tutorials/</link>
      <description>Five new HTML tutorials have been added</description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

and my code is like that :

```
 ...
   $feed->set_feed_url('http://localhost/rss/flux/rss.xml');
   $feed->init();
   $feed->handle_content_type();
    foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item){      
        echo $item->get_title();
        echo $item->get_source();
    }
```

but the function get_source() return NULL 
do you have any adea please

Comment: I'm not familiar with simpleplie. Can you use simplexml or domdocument?

Comment: I have already a program with simplepie and I don't want to redo everything :(

Answer (score 0):

If anybody needs the solution after three years, the problem is due the url attribute inside "source" tag

This is not recognized by simplepie:

```
<source url="http://www.reddit.com/.rss">reddit.com:what's new online!</source>
```

This is recognized by simplepie:

```
<source>reddit.com:what's new online!</source>
```

Solution is accessing the "source" tag using the more general method "get_item_tags".

```
$sourceTags = $item->get_item_tags(NULL, "source");
$source = $sourceTags[0]['data'];
echo $source;
```

Answer (score 0):

And to get to the URL attribute, use:

```
$sourceTags = $item->get_item_tags(NULL, "source");
$source = $sourceTags[0]['attribs']['']['url'];
$url = esc_url($source);
```